# How ask form submit confirmation with jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, confirmation

I'm working on a WordPress site and I need to ask confirmation for user deletion.

When the button is clicked no confirmation asked and the form is always submitted.
I tried with a `submit` event and `event.preventDefault` method but it doesn't work. Which is the most correct and working method to achieve this?

```
<button type="submit" id="delete_patient" name="delete_patient" form="add_patient_form" formmethod="post" formaction="<?=parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH )?>" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><?=__( 'Elimina paziente', 'halluxvalgus' )?></button>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
  jQuery("#delete_patient").on("click", function() {
    return confirm("<?=__( 'Sei sicuro?', 'halluxvalgus' )?>"); 
  });
```

Comment: Calling `event.preventDefault()` in the `submit` event handler is the best way to do what you need. If it does not please edit the question to include that code, and also details of any error messages that appear in the console

Comment: You can accept my answer if it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863030/how-ask-form-submit-confirmation-with-jquery-in-wordpress/54863284#54863284

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to override the default method.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

  jQuery("#delete_patient").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var r = confirm("<?=__( 'Sei sicuro?', 'halluxvalgus' )?>");
    if (r == true) {

       // "You pressed OK!";

    } else {
       // "You pressed Cancel!";

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click trigger this code

```
function confirmDelete(){
    var x = confirm('Your text here');
    if(x){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

And your delete button must look like this

```
 <button onClick="return confirmDelete()">Delete</button>
```

On clicking that button an alert will come up either to proceed or not, before executing the delete code.